# SpringBootApplication with Spring Starter Web error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Even the most simple SpringBoot Application developed in STS with Spring Web Starter is not working for me. I can run the app initially without error, but when I try to access with localhost:8080, I got the following messages on console:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x03/0xaf70x14n0xc70x8dF0x120x060x07e20xf70xe60xc30xff0xfa0xb7lXJz10x0d?0xf00x980x91dz:]. HTTP method names must be tokens.

The application is only a default spring boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestewebApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestewebApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

What could be the error?

Comment: how are you doing the request? through your browser? postman? is it http, or https? would you mind to put an example of the request(included headers)?

Comment: I was doing the request from a browser (chrome). After your comment, I discovered that is working well in a HTTP Client (Insomnia)  and on Firefox. The problem is with Chrome.